# PHP Wrapping custom items inside loop Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently creating a slider which consists of products. 
Currently I have managed to wrap every 2 items in div using this code:

```
  <div class="frame crazy" id="crazy">
  <div class="slidee">
  <?php if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) :  
    $i = 0;
    while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post();    
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
    $value = get_field( "alternate_image", get_the_id() );
    $titl = get_field( "title", get_the_id() );
    $big = get_field( "big_section", get_the_id() );
     if ( $i % 2 ==  0) : ?>
      <div class="op" <?if ($big==1){?>style="width:850px !important;"<?}?>>
      <?php endif; 
      $_pf = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_id());
      $variations =     $_pf->get_available_variations();
      $vrt = count($variations);
      ?>
      <div data-hv="<?php echo $value; ?>" data-titleContent="<a href='<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>'><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>" data-tipso-content="<span class='varaition'>this item has <?php echo $vrt; ?> variation(s)</span><a class='bty' href='<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>'>details</a>" data-url="<? echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="cola <?php if($big==1){?>big<?}?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')" data-mg="<?php echo $image[0];?>">
      <?php if($titl==1) { ?>
      <h2><a href='<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>'><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p class="slu"><a href='<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>'>shop now ></a> </p>
      <?php } ?>
            </div>
      <?php if ( $i % 2 != 0 ) : ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $i++; endwhile;  ?>

            <?php if ( $i % 2 != 0 ) : ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif;?>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This code wraps every two products like this:

```
<div class="op">
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="product2">
//content
</div>
</div>
<div class="op">
<div class="product3">
//content
</div>
<div class="product4">
//content
</div>
</div>
```

But I need to fetch custom number of posts according to product meta. So that the number of products can be varying like this:

```
<div class="op">
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="op">
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
<div class="product1">
//content
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible using product meta or any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

this line in your code:

```
if ( $i % 2 ==  0) : ?>
```

contains the loop number, change that to be a variable and set that variable from the meta data, so:

```
$loopmeta=metadata_retriever();
if ( $i % $loopmeta == 0 ) : ?>
```

You will have to write the `metadata_retriever()` function and put some error checking around the retrieval of the `$loopmeta` variable to ensure it comes back as a valid integer (not 0, nor 12.735 for instance :-) )

Comment: I have tried using this but if i change the value of 2 it doesn`t work .It just works for 2 products only. I am creating a slider like [this](http://www.gucci.com/int/category/m/travel_bags___luggage#look86083lookA113) which consists of dynamic number of items!

Comment: so, did you change the value of `2` everywhere in your code that you use it to the variable number of items value? as you check it 3 times in the code you posted.  I would recommend refactoring this as well so that you don't mix php and html together.  use functions to create the output strings and concatenate them together then `print $str` at the end.  You'll see errors and optimisation possibilities much clearer then.